# I want to compare from date and to date with date order using search orm in odoo

Tags: date, datetime, odoo

I want to compare `from_date` and `to_date` with `date_order` using search orm in odoo.

I just want to extract date alone because in `date_order` it is given date with date time. how to work with it ?

here is my code :

```
from_date = fields.Date(string="From", default="Today")
to_date = fields.Date(string="To")
 
def update_commission(self):
sale_br = self.env['sale.order']
sale_sr = sale_br.search([('date_order', '=',   self.from_date)])
```

Comment: What odoo version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function like this:

```
def update_commission(self):
    sale_br = self.env['sale.order']
    sale_sr = sale_br.search([]).filtered(lambda sale: sale.date_order.date < self.from_date)
```

If you are working in odoo's past version like 10,11 than you need to convert this datetime into datetime object because when you call this field it will return date in string format so you need to do `fields.Datetime.from_string(sale.date_order.date)`

Comment: If you satisfied with answer please accept it so others will know the update.